# Pegar valor do Select Option e do Checkbox de várias linhas

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Preciso fazer uma listagem de funcionários que são vinculados a centros de custos e preciso dizer se esse funcionário é liderança dentro desse centro de custo.

Tentei montar um select e o um checkbox adicionado clicando no botão de +, mas não consigo pegar os valores correspondentes com jquery.

Aqui está o html

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="intIdCentroCusto" class="col-lg-2 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <table class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">

                    <tr ><td class="bd_titulo" width="10">Centro de Custo</td><td class="bd_titulo">Liderança</td></tr>
                    <tr class="linhas"  style="width: 800px">
                        <td  style="width: 2000px">
                            <select data-minlength-error='Selecione pelo menos um'
                                                data-placeholder='Digite ou selecione' data-minlength='1'
                                                multiple='multiple' name='arrCentroCusto[]'
                                                id='arrCentroCusto'
                                                class="js-basic-multiple form-control" required>
<option value="1">Centro custo 1</option>
<option value="2">Centro custo 2</option>
<option value="3">Centro custo 3</option>
</select>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 300px">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input name='boolLideranca[]' value='1' <?php echo $this->modelo->boolLideranca==1 ? 'checked' : ''; ?> type="checkbox" class="boolLideranca"> Sim
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td><a href="#" class="removerCampo" title="Remover linha"><img src="imagens/details_close.png" border="0" /></a></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr><td colspan="4">
                            <a href="#" class="adicionarCampo" title="Adicionar item"><img src="imagens/details_open.png" border="0" /></a>
                        </td>
                </table>
        </div>
```

e aqui estou tentando pegar as variaveis com jquery

```
var lideranca = [] ; // inicia o array;
var arrCentroCusto = []; // inicia o array

b = 0;
i = 0; // ÍNDICE INICIAL DO ARRAY
$('#arrCentroCusto option:selected').each(function() {
    arrCentroCusto[i] = $(this).val(); // PEGANDO OS IDS DAS OPÇÕES SELECIONADAS
    i++; // INCREMENTANDO O ÍNDICE
});

$(".boolLideranca:checked").each(function() {
    lideranca[b] = $(this).val(); // PEGANDO OS IDS DAS OPÇÕES SELECIONADAS
    b++;
});
```

Preciso pegar essas informações para salvar na tabela o centro de custo e se é liderança.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: onde está o código que adiciona os elemento clicando no "+"? Seu seletor para encontrar os itens selecionados está começando com id ("#arrCentroCusto"), como só pode ter um elemento com esse ID, como você vai verificar os outros `select`? não seria melhor usar uma classe para isso? Por ID só vai ler o primeiro

Comment: Há erros de ecrita no seu Html, o select não foi fechado.

Comment: Este não é o código original, o original está fechado e dentro de um php, eu só coloquei ai um exemplo.

Comment: Coloquei o .arrCentroCusto e mesmo assim só busca 1 valor

Comment: Por que preciso dizer a liderança por centro de custo e não no geral. @Diogo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o problema, mas tive que mudar o checkbox para um select para funcionar.

Vou deixar a resposta aqui para quem quiser usar no futuro.

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="intIdCentroCusto" class="col-lg-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <table class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">

                <tr ><td class="bd_titulo" width="10">Centro de Custo</td><td class="bd_titulo">Liderança</td></tr>
                <tr class="linhas"  style="width: 800px">
                    <td  style="width: 2000px">
                        <select data-minlength-error='Selecione pelo menos um'
                                            data-placeholder='Digite ou selecione' data-minlength='1'
                                            multiple='multiple' name='arrCentroCusto[]'
                                            id='arrCentroCusto'
                                            class="js-basic-multiple form-control" required>
                                            <option value="1">Centro custo 1</option>
                                            <option value="2">Centro custo 2</option>
                                            <option value="3">Centro custo 3</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 300px">
                        <select name='boolLideranca[]'
                                        class='form-control boolLideranca' required>
                                    <option value="0">Não</option>
                                    <option value="1">Sim</option>
                    </td>
                    <td><a href="#" class="removerCampo" title="Remover linha"><img src="imagens/details_close.png" border="0" /></a></td>
                </tr>

                <tr><td colspan="4">
                        <a href="#" class="adicionarCampo" title="Adicionar item"><img src="imagens/details_open.png" border="0" /></a>
                    </td>
            </table>
    </div>

    <script>
    var lideranca = [] ; // inicia o array;
        var arrCentroCusto = []; // inicia o array

        //var contador = ($("tr.linhas").length);

        var i = 0;
        $('.arrCentroCusto').each(function() {
            arrCentroCusto[i] = $(this).val(); // PEGANDO OS IDS DAS OPÇÕES SELECIONADAS
            i++; // INCREMENTANDO O ÍNDICE
        });

        var b = 0;
        $('.boolLideranca').each(function() {
            lideranca[b] = $(this).val(); // PEGANDO OS IDS DAS OPÇÕES SELECIONADAS
            b++;
        });
    </script>
```